# Facebook graph api - Cannot create offers

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the facebook graph api to programmatically create offers on a page, of which the user is an admin of.
I am sure the user is an admin of that page, still I am getting an error to check my admin permission levels (Error below). Any idea why? Any help is appreciated.

If it is of any help, I have added the following scope to my requests: `{scope: 'manage_pages,publish_pages'}`

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid parameter",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 1528104,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Check Your Admin Permission Level",
    "error_user_msg": "Only some admins of your Page are able to create and edit offers. Talk to the person responsible for your Page about your admin permission level.",
    "fbtrace_id": "FgBVmH5BTW0"
  }
}
```

A snapshot of my code is as follows:

```
accessToken = req.session.access_token;
    FB.setAccessToken(accessToken);
        FB.api("page-name", {fields: "access_token,id"}, function (res) {
          var pageId = res.id;
          var pageAccessToken = res.access_token;
          FB.setAccessToken(pageAccessToken);

          FB.api(pageId + "/offers", 'post', {
            title: "Test title",
            expiration_time: 'some datetime',
            message: "Test offer 1"
          }, function (res2) {
            resp.send(res2);
          });
```

Comment: it is a facebook bug, confirmed by facebook https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/641471189346328/

Comment: according to the link above, this should be fixed  by now

Comment: Fixed; apologies!

Comment: Thank you @nikos.svnk & Dean J